# Add a point at the x intercept

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, manipulate, drawing

I am trying to add a point in a plot where the curve intercepts the x axis i.e. f[x] = 0 
I tried doing an epilog inside an if statement in Plot[] , and it didn't work.
here is my code so far

```
f[pi_, p_] = (10)*(p - pi);
g[p_] = 10*(p);
Manipulate[Plot[{f[pi, p], g[p]}, {p, 0, 50}, PlotLabels -> {"Water & slat", "Pure Water"}, AxesLabel -> {\[CapitalDelta]P, Solvent - Flux}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium],AxesStyle -> Directive[Black], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], {pi, 10, 100}, {p, 0, 40}]
```

Comment: Instead of an `Epilog`, you could use the mesh options, e.g., `Plot[.., MeshFunctions->{#2&}, Mesh->{{0}}, MeshStyle->Directive[PointSize[Large],Red]]`

Answer (score 2):

```
f[pi_, p_] = 10*(p - pi);
g[p_] = 10*p;
```

Clearly, `f[pi, p] == 0` for `p == pi`

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[pi, p], g[p]}, {p, 0, 100},
  PlotLabels -> {"Water & slat", "Pure Water"},
  AxesLabel -> {ΔP, Solvent - Flux},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium],
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black],
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
    Tooltip[Point[{pi, 0}], {pi, 0}]},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 103}, {-1000, 1000}}],
 {{pi, 40}, 10, 100, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]